# Vim gets unresponsive when toggling NERDTREE

Tags: vim, nerdtree

i'm new to Vim , and loving it, but i have an annoying problem. Whenever i toggle NERDTREE , i get a message

> Please wait, caching a Large dir...

then vim becomes unresponsive till i quit it...

I don't know what's the default directory, but if it's large one , can i change it ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, I think I just [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/265829/vim-gets-unresponsive-when-toggling-nerdtree/265864#265864) the very same question on superuser.